# Java equivalent of .NET Action<T> and Func<T,U>, etc

Tags: java, .net, functor, strategy-pattern

Are there any standard generic "callback" or "function/method" types in Java, like `System.Action<T>` or `System.Func<T,U>` in .NET?

In my concrete case, I need a class that wraps a method that takes one (generic) parameter of type `T` and returns nothing (i.e. `void`).

Yes, it's easy enough to create such a class/interface for myself, but I'd prefer a standard library class if there is one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't believe there's anything in the standard library like this, no (at the time of writing, 2010). Other libraries have them - things like Guice's `Provider<T>` and Guava's `Function<F, T>`, `Supplier<T>` and `Predicate<T>`... so if you're using libraries already, you might want to look into what they provide in this direction.

(EDIT: As noted, those are interfaces which return things - so similar to `Func<T, U>` but *not* similar to `Action<T>`.)

Comment: How would any of these be equivalent?  Each of the items you suggested is expected to return a value.  See my [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9007008/403455).

Comment: @glenviewjeff: They're not similar to `Action<T>`, but they're similar to `Func<T, U>`.

Comment: @glenviewjeff: You can always use [java.lang.Void](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) if you don't need the return value. A "standardised" `Func<T,U>` is better than nothing, imo.

Comment: This is why I love C# over Java.

Comment: Java8 provides `Function<T, R>` and `Consumer<T>` as well as other set of common functional interfaces [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) that are similar to the delegates mentioned in the question.

Comment: @ZenLulz: Indeed, it does now. I'm not going to revise all answers from 7 years ago though, I'm afraid...

Answer (score 2):

Java standard library doesn't provide any such classes.

You can use [Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org/) library which provides `fj.F1<T, fj.Unit>` which is basically equivalent of `System.Action<T>` from .NET.