# Is there a built-in Java type that guarantees an execute(T t) method?

Tags: java, functor, strategy-pattern

It seems the need for a type like the following would be so ubiquitous that something like it should be already built into Java:

```
public interface Executer<T> {
   void execute(T object);
}
```

It can then be used in other classes like this trivial example that calls a bunch of executers on an object.

```
class Handler<T> implements Executer<T> {
   List<Executer<T>> executerList;

   Handler(List<Executer<T>> executer) {
      this.executerList = executer;
   }

   void execute(T t) {
      for (Executer<T> executer : this.executerList) {
         executer.execute(t);
      }
   }
}
```

Is there a built-in type equivalent or a common library equivalent?  Is there a name for this concept?

Comment: What should implementations of your Executer interface do, given they have to be invoked on a specific type T.

Comment: Is `Runnable` close to what you're looking for?

Comment: I'd agree that Runnable would be sufficient. I'm not really sure what your construct adds. There's also the concurrent Executor classes I suppose but these work off Runnable and exist to manage concurrent invocations.

Comment: @wmorrison365 implementations would perform an operation on a T object.

Comment: @aardvarkk Runnable's run() method doesn't accept a parameter.

Comment: @glenviewjeff I know, it'll do something with a T but you're going to have a TExecuter to do that (i.e. something that knows all about your T). What's the purpose for wrapping it? What does your handler add?

Comment: You would create an implementation of `Runnable` with a constructor and setters. You instantiate your `MyRunnable(mydata);` then allow the `Thread`, `Executor`, `Timer`, etc deal with it - i.e. execute it's `run` method.

Comment: @wmorrison365, it adds the ability to use dependency injection with Executers, allows separation of concerns, allows you to write classes that take lists of Executers to perform a list of tasks, etc.

Comment: @wmorrison365 I think you're misunderstanding.  This has nothing to do with threading, only performing an action (i.e., a simple method call.)

Comment: Well, in short, I've not seen a framework resembling this in terms of providing the pattern. I can only think of java.util.concurrent.Executor but that deals with managing invocation of `Runnables` in a multi-threaded environment. `Runnable` also resembles this but, again, I don't think you're especially interested in a multi-threaded env.

Comment: @wmorrison365 Correct, this has nothing to do with threading or concurrency.  See my revised sample code for a better use case.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244582/java-equivalent-of-net-actiont-and-funct-u-etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the name of the concept is the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).  Effectively you are encapsulating an algorithm, and this makes it easier to swap out one strategy for another or to apply a number of strategies.

This design pattern is very easy to implement, and the `execute` method need not take only a single argument of a specific type.  As such, I doubt you will find a built-in Java type, but it is a well-known design pattern.

Comment: Yeah, or possibly the Command pattern. This would provide good separation of concerns.

Comment: Oh, of course it's the strategy pattern.  I don't know why I didn't recognize it.  I'm a bit surprised that this specific interface doesn't come up frequently enough to warrant a built-in type.

Comment: @glenviewjeff Well I think then you'd need one for Executor<T1>, one for Executor<T1, T2>, one for Executor<T1, T2, T3>, etc.  That might bet a bit strange to include as a built-in type...especially when defining the interface is so easy to do for your specific use-case.

Comment: That wouldn't be without [precedent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549311.aspx)... although I agree with your point more than Microsoft's choice to only implement the <T1> and <T1,T2>.

Answer (score 2):

The closest I know of is Guava's [`Function<F,T>`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html).

I don't think there's anything in the standard library that does exactly what you're asking. `Runnable` is somewhat close, but takes no arguments.

P.S. I think "function" or "functor" is exactly the right name for this concept.

Comment: I agree that while Guava's `Function` type could actually be substituted, my use doesn't fit `Function`'s intention.